# Trying to add item to linq select statement in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a long result set in linq which is put in ratestest, I am mapping the result to ChargeElementsNullable. The issue is this doesnt include a fee record which is

```
var fees = (from r in _dbContext.Rates
                   where r.RateTypeFK == RateType.Fee && (r.LocaleBW & localeid) > 0 && (r.PolicyBW & policy.BitWise) > 0 && r.RateExclude == 0
                   select r);
```

So I want to add fees to ratestest and I could do that mapping again so I can use the add method, but I dont want to do that long winded mapping just for one record.. I am trying to add it to ratestest directly instead.. but no joy... I tried using DefaultIfEmpty expecting a left join.. but fee still wasnt in there..

```
var ratestest = (from qi in quoteInputs                         
                     join r in _dbContext.Rates on qi.RatePK equals r.RatePK
                     join fee in fees on r.RatePK equals fee.RatePK into feecontainer
                     from fee in feecontainer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join c in _dbContext.Covers on r.CoverCalcFK equals c.CoverPK into covers
                     from c in covers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join rt in _dbContext.RateTypes on qi.RateTypeFK equals rt.RateTypePK
                     where rt.Ratable == 1 ||
                     rt.RateTypePK == RateType.PostCode ||
                     rt.RateTypePK == RateType.Fee// employersliab.Contains(r.InputFK)
                     select new ChargeElementsNullable
                     {
                         PolicyFK = quote.PolicyFK,
                         InputFK = r.InputFK,
                         LongRate = r.LongRate,
                         RateLabel = r.RateLabel,
                         CoverName = c.CoverName,
                         CoverFK = r.CoverCalcFK,
                         CoverBW = c.BitWise,
                         ListRatePK = r.ListRatePK,
                         RatePK = r.RatePK,
                         RateName = r.RateName,
                         Rate = r.Rate,
                         Threshold = r.Threshold,
                         Excess = r.Excess,
                         DivBy = r.DivBy,
                         DiscountFirstRate = r.DiscountFirstRate,
                         DiscountSubsequentRate = r.DiscountSubsequentRate,
                         HazardRating = r.HazardRating,
                         TableFirstColumn = r.TableFirstColumn,
                         TableChildren = r.TableChildren,
                         RateTypeFK = r.RateTypeFK,
                         PageNo = r.PageNo,
                         SumInsured = qi.SumInsured,
                         NoItems = qi.NoItems,
                         RateValue = qi.RateValue,
                         TriggerCode = rt.TriggerCode,
                         Territory = territory
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: By adding you mean `Concat`enating two sequences?

Comment: Yes, I mean concatenating, thanks

Comment: What type is `quoteInputs`? Where does it come from? Separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a model with two properties one for quoteInputs                          and another for fees. Then you just need to select both of them.
Eg:

```
class model1 
{
     public QuoteInputs quoteInputs {get;set;}
     public Fees fees{get;set;}    
}
```

Then you call use this model in the select clause and assign this model tables directly.

Now let's take your code and change select like this :

```
var ratestest = (from qi in quoteInputs                         
                 join r in _dbContext.Rates on qi.RatePK equals r.RatePK
                 join fee in fees on r.RatePK equals fee.RatePK into feecontainer
                 from fee in feecontainer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join c in _dbContext.Covers on r.CoverCalcFK equals c.CoverPK into covers
                 from c in covers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join rt in _dbContext.RateTypes on qi.RateTypeFK equals rt.RateTypePK
                 where rt.Ratable == 1 ||
                 rt.RateTypePK == RateType.PostCode ||
                 rt.RateTypePK == RateType.Fee// employersliab.Contains(r.InputFK)
                 select new model1{
                    quoteInputs   = qi,
                    fees = fee
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: how do I select the fee property?

Comment: So far I have this.. { var modeltest = new Model1 { quoteInputs = quoteInputs, fees = fee };

            var rates = (from qi in modeltest.quoteInputs
                         join r in _dbContext.Rates on qi.RatePK equals r.RatePK }

Comment: That was a typo. You can select like : select new model1 { quoteInputs = qi, fees = fee, ....}

Comment: Yes correct. You just need to add properties into the model for more tables and then you select directly the complete table from joins. That's it

Comment: Are you saying the fee property is used like another join? but I tried that with a standalone fee record.

Comment: Yes,and fees table can be left join or inner join. You can select in both the cases.

Comment: Could you give an example please? I mean how will fee property be joined as it doesnt exist in quoteinputs

Comment: Just edited the post with model1 in select clause. Check once

Comment: Thanks, that is great,

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments, you are seeking for `Concat` method ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx)). This can be done like this:

```
var fees = from ...
           select new ChargeElementsNullable {
                Prop1 = (some value),
                Prop2 = (other value)
            }

var ratestest = from ...
           select new ChargeElementsNullable {
                Prop1 = (some value),
                Prop2 = (other value)
            }

var bothtogether = fees.Concat(ratestest);
```

Be sure, that you have <del>all properties in **exactly same order** and</del> all properties are in **both** selects. Otherwise Linq2Sql will fail when obtaining results. (I assume from your code that you are using it)

As @Cris correctly pointed out in comments, same order is not necessary.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you don't need the properties in the same order here. If it was an anonymous object it might be a different matter but since we are creating an `IEnumerable<ChargeElementsNullable>` then all that matters is that they are both the same type.

Comment: No I want to avoid mapping fee to ChargeElementsNullable seperately as that is 20 odd lines of code. I just want to add it to my ratestest select somehow.

Comment: @Luke ok then, can you provide minimal example of your DB structure? I believe it would help to create one and single query you are looking for.

Comment: @Chris thx for correction. I remeber having difficulties when using Linq2Sql and `Concat`. And filling all properties in both queries solved it, even if I used `select` with *specific* type.

Comment: The way you are selecting into different tables is great!! Thanks

Comment: @Luke if your source tables are different (and from your code I believe that is true in this case), you need to create two queries in any case and it is not possible to do it other way (by a single query). Anyway, don't be afraid to upvote usefull answers :)